# Billboard JS : hovering over one chart, shows tooltip across all charts

Tags: vue.js, charts

I am using BillboardJS (https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/) with VueJs.
I have been able to draw a vertical line across all the charts by using **onclick** event of the library.
what I want to do is, show the tooltip and the vertical hover line on mouseover event on any one graph.

I have been trying to figure this problem out but no success so far.

This same effect is done for ChartJS in the below example

````
```
https://jsfiddle.net/vikas12118/k4oveLsb/
```
````

Comment: Please don't try to bypass the anti-linking mechanism when posting a question. It's there for a reason: People may not be able or willing to visit an external link to view your code. Instead, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] of your issue, including the shortest code necessary to reproduce your problem and what you've tried so far to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tooltip.linked](https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/release/latest/doc/Options.html#.tooltip) option for that.

```js
var chart = bb.generate({
  data: {
    ...
  },
  tooltip: {
    linked: true
  },
  bindto: "#linkedTooltips"
});

var chart2 = bb.generate({
  data: {
    ...
  },
  tooltip: {
    linked: true
  },
  bindto: "#linkedTooltips_2"
});
```

You can find the working example from below link

- https://naver.github.io/billboard.js/demo/#Tooltip.LinkedTooltips